# Using <mvc:view-controller> for tiles

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, tiles

Can we use `mvc:view-controller` tag for displaying a tiles view.

**Eg:** If we have a tiles definition of the form definition,

```
name="userLogon.page" 
template="webapp/app/layout/baseLayoutExterior.jsp" 
extends="basePageDefinition"
```

Can we write `mvc:view-controller path="/logon" view-name="userLogon.page"` in our `servlet.xml` file.

I am getting an **HTTP 404 RESOURCE NOT FOUND ERROR** on this whereas a normal `hello.jsp` page is displayed without problems.

Please help i am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

You need to add a `TilesConfigurer` and a `TilesView`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
    id="tilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
    id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Example Layout.xml located in `webapp/WEB-INF/layouts`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

  <definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jspx" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/menu.jspx" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx" />
  </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

one of the view.xml's located in `webapp/WEB-INF/views/bookmarks`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="bookmarks/show">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/bookmarks/show.jspx" />
    </definition>       
    <definition extends="default" name="bookmarks/list">...</definition>
    <definition extends="default" name="bookmarks/create">...</definition>      
    <definition extends="default" name="bookmarks/update">...</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

One controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/bookmarks")
@Controller
public class BookmarkController {
    ...
    /** Return the show page. */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
    public ModelAndView show(@PathVariable("id") long bookmarkId) {
        return new ModelAndView("bookmarks/show", "bookmark", bookmarkDao.getBzId(bookmarkId));
    }
}
```